# Threading Structure

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wrote some C# code and in it I initiate a class by placing it in its own thread so it doesnt freeze up my GUI from where I initiate it:

This is from my Form Class:

```
    Execute_Recipe execute;
    execute = new Execute_Recipe(XCoordinatesList, YCoordinatesList, Zref, Voltref,
              widget, record, filename);
    Thread executethread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(execute.RunRecipe));
```

And then in my Execute Class I create a new class to record the data. This is from my execute class:

```
    record1 = new Record_Recipe(XCoordinateList1, YCoordinateList1, Zref1, Voltref1, filename1);
```

And finally in my record class I send the data to a new form. To be displayd. So in the end all of the sub classes I initiate are all created within this thread. I know the structure is absolutley crazy right now, the software is deep in its development stage, but here is my question:

How can I keep BOTH Form Classes in their own threads while having all the execution and recording of my procedure in its own thread?

Do I create 1 thread for my execution, 1 thread for my recording, and a backgrounworker for my displaying? and then talk between threads? (from what I understand talking between threads is not easy)

I am only an intermediate programmer at best and I thank you in advance if you able / willing to help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking between threads is very easy in C#

```
            yourform.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                yourform.button.Text = "new label";
                //More stuff here
            });
```

kind of construct can be used from a worker thread to updated the UI thread. If you are creating lot of non UI threads that have smaller lifetime consider using a [**ThreadPool**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead.

For simple ui updates also look at [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) that lets you updated data bound controls easily.

Comment: so I use this on my display form ?

Comment: No the code snippet is a example to be used from non UI thread to updated UI

Comment: ahh, ok i just did some reading on the beginInvoke method on codeprojects that helps, thank you!

Comment: thank you very much this worked perfectly, and I understand the concept now :) I learned something new today :D oh how I love this community, I have learned more through this than I have in my programming classes :D thank you again

Comment: @kenetik Also look at edit regarding INotifyPropertyChagned and data binding

Answer (score 0):

The thread you call `Application.Run()` on is the thread that must do all the GUI stuff. The `Windows.Forms.Control` base class has an `Invoke()` method that allows a delegate to be called whenever the GUI thread is idle (a `Form` is such a `Control`). There are quite a few other mechanisms in .NET to communicate between threads.

Communicating to a non-GUI thread is a bit getting used to, but there are quite a few options.  An example of for instance using the `WaitHandle` is as follows:

- receiving thread waits for a signal
- sending thread writes data
- sending thread sets signal
- receiving thread reads data and performs the task

Usually one thread ("the main thread") leads and the others either wait for work, or are created, do the work and are destroyed afterwards.

I suggest you check the `System.Threading` namespace on MSDN and see what's available. Also http://www.albahari.com/threading/ seems to cover it all.